# MSAD Group member configuration

Tags: active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

We are trying to setup Group filters in MSAD for our Hyperion Application.Our current issue is ,MSAD filter is not pulling the group members

For DM- Parent MSAD Group
DM_HFM -Child Group &  DM_PLAN-Child groups
DM_HFM  has 3 Child msad group members

DM_HFM_READ

DM_HFM_WRITE

DM_PLAN_Read

DM_PLAN_Write

The below Group filter query in Hyperion

(&(objectClass=group)(|(cn=DM_HYP_HFM)(cn=DM_PLAN)))
fetches only above the groups

I need to fetch the group members too.is that possible,If so please pass on the sample query

Group member tree in MSAD

"CN=DM_HFM_READ,OU=Orcl,OU=Sec Groups,OU=Acts,DC=TESTINC,DC=com"
"CN=DM_HFM_WRITE,OU=Orcl,OU=Sec Groups,OU=Acts,DC=TESTINC,DC=com"

Comment: If you deal with nested groups you have to expand group nembership recursively on the client side or use ldap_matching_rule_in_chain filter to perform the operation on the server side. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx the drawback of the filter is performance and you search may become cpu intensive on domain controller

Answer (score 0):

To resolve all members (including nested) Security Groups (requires at least Windows 2003 SP2)

You need to use a [filter similar to](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+Group+Related+Searches-ResolvesAllMembersIncludingNestedSecurityGroupsRequiresAtLeastWindows2003SP2):
(|(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=DM_HFM_READ)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=DM_HFM_READ)...)